# I want to get sum of day sale report with condition

Tags: sql

I want to get document total of sales , in all the line of item summary of the day.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/61dc69/1

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sale` (
  `item_ID` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `'date` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `amount` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `qty` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 )

INSERT INTO `sale` (`item_ID`, `date`, `amount`,  `qty `) VALUES

  ('2', '20190120', '10050','1'),
  ('2', '20190120', '10050','1'),
  ('4', '20190120', '9045','1'),
  ('6', '20190121', '10050','1'),
  ('4', '20190121', '20050','2')
```

```
select   item_ID,date,sum( amount) as amount,
sum(qty) as qty from sale
group by item_ID,date
```

I want to  calculate document total per day`date` as a filter,  and the amount and qty is based on `item and date` as filter

My expected output is as below:

```
item_ID  date      amount  qty  document total
2        20190120  20100    2    29145
4        20190120   9045    1    29145
6        20190121  10050    1    30100
4        20190121  20050    2    30100
```

Comment: You tagged SQL Server but your code and fiddle is MySql. Set the corect tag.

Comment: @@Angel...I Have Edited my Answer...Please Check Out....as per Your Suggestion and Logic...

Answer (score 2):

**Your Expected output**

As per your Suggestion...you told that data is also calculated based date also...

```
CREATE TABLE sale (
  item_ID int NOT NULL,
  date VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  amount varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  qty varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 )

INSERT INTO sale (item_ID, date, amount,  qty ) VALUES

  ('2', '09/09/2019', '10050','1'),
  ('2', '09/09/2019', '10050','1'),
  ('4', '09/09/2019', '9045','1'),
  ('6', '10/10/2019', '10050','1'),
  ('4', '10/10/2019', '20050','2')
```

**Your Table Structure Should be look like this:-**

```
select   item_ID,
CAST(date AS DATE) date,
sum(Convert(int,amount)) as amount,
sum(Convert(int,qty)) as qty from sale
group by item_ID, CAST(date AS DATE)
```

[image]

**Note:- I am doing this in SQL Server as per Tag Specified "SQL"**

Comment: Thank you... but i need one more field to calculate document total per day.

Answer (score 2):

```
select qty_table.item_ID, qty_table.date,amount_table.sumamount, qty_table.sumqty, 
from 
(select date, item_ID, sum(qty) as sumqty from sale
group by date , item_ID ) qty_table 
join 
( select date,sum(amount) as sumamount from sale
group by date ) amount_table on  amount_table.date = qty_table.date
```

Output:

```
    | item_ID |     date | sumqty | sumamount |
    |---------|----------|--------|-----------|
    |       2 | 20190120 |      2 |     29145 |
    |       4 | 20190120 |      1 |     29145 |
    |       4 | 20190121 |      2 |     30100 |
    |       6 | 20190121 |      1 |     30100 |
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/61dc69/9